# Prove that $(l^p,\|.\|_p)$ is a Banach space for $p\geq 1$.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

$(l^p,\|.\|_p)$ is a Banach space for $p\geq 1$.

---

**Proof:** Let $(x^n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $l^p$, where $x^n=(x^n_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Then choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for each $m>n>N, \|x^n-x^m\|_p<\epsilon.$ Then for each $m>n>N,$ 
$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j^n-x_j^m|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}<\epsilon.$$

Thus for each $k,$ 
$$m>n>N\implies|x^n_k-x^m_k|\leq\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j^n-x_j^m|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}<\epsilon. $$ 
Hence the sequence $(x^n_k)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy for all $k.$ Now put $x_k=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n_k$ for all $k$. Since $(x^n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy it is bounded. Therefore, $$\exists M>0:\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\|x^n\|_p<M.$$

Hence $\sum_{j=1}^m|x_j^n|<M^p$ for each $m,n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Fix $m$. Then $\sum_{j=1}^m|x_j|<M^p$ as $n\to\infty,$ whence $\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j|<\infty$ or $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\in l^p$.

Now fix $n>N$ and observe that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j^n-x_j^m|^p<\epsilon^p$ for each $m>n$. Then for each $m>n$ and for each $k,\  \sum_{j=1}^k|x_j^n-x_j^m|^p<\epsilon^p$.

Letting $m\to\infty$ yields $\sum_{j=1}^k|x_j^n-x_j|^p \leq\epsilon^p$ for all $k$. Thus $\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j^n-x_j|^p \leq\epsilon^p$.

Thus $(\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j^n-x_j|^p)^\frac{1}{p} \leq\epsilon$ or rather $\|x^n-x\|_p<\epsilon$ where $x=(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, and the proof is complete.

---

Is this proof alright? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the proof is correct, except that $\sum_{j=1}^m|x_j^n|<M^p$ should be $\sum_{j=1}^m|x_j^n|^p<M^p$. Same for $\sum_{j=1}^m|x_j|<M^p$, which should be $\sum_{j=1}^m|x_j|^p<M^p$.